# Перенаправление на другой домен без смены URL | nginx

Tags: nginx, url, веб-сервер, redirect, configuration

Есть домен **domain.ru** и другой домен **newdomain.ru**. При переходе на **domain.ru/blog** должен идти редирект на **newdomain.ru**, но без смены URL в строке поиска. То есть при переходе на **domain.ru/blog** должен отдаваться контент с **newdomain.ru**, но URL должен оставать тем же. 
Пробовал через *proxy_pass*, различные *rewrite*, но не смог решить проблему.

Comment: и всё же это - proxy_pass. может быть не хватает `proxy_set_header        Host                   'newdomain.ru';` и проброса каких-то других данных

Comment: Если несложно, приведите пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: в вопросе недостаточно данных для корректного примера. дал ответ, который, скорее, руководство к самостоятельному чтению документации и экспериментам

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    server_name domain.ru;
    listen 80;

    default_type    text/html;


    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-for     $remote_addr;


    location /blog/ {
        rewrite             /blog/(.*)  /$1  break;
        proxy_pass          http://newdomain.ru;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header    Host  'newdomain.ru';
        sub_filter       'newdomain.ru'  'domain.ru';
        sub_filter_once  off;
    }
}
```